# How to use a LinkButton inside gridview to delete selected username in the code-behind file?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, linkbutton

I have a "UserDetail" table in my "JobPost.mdf".
I have a "Gridview1" showing the column from "UserDetail" table,which has a primary key "UserName".
This "UserName" is originally saved using Membership class function.
Now I add a "Delete" linkbutton to the GridView1. This "Delete" is not autogenerate button,I dragged inside the column itemtemplate from ToolBox.
The GridView1's columns now become "Delete_LinkButton"+"UserName"(within the UserDetail table)+"City"(within the UserDetail table)+"IsAdmin"(within the UserDetail table)

What I need is that by clicking this "delete_linkButton",it will ONLY delete the entire User Entity on the same row (link by the corresponding "UserName") from the "UserDetail" table,as well as delete all information from the AspNetDB.mdf (User,Membership,UserInRole,etc).

I would like to fireup a user confirm,but not mandatory. At least I am trying to make it functional in the correct way.

```
for example:

Command     UserName    City           IsAdmin
delete           ken       Los Angles          TRUE
delete           jim        Toronto        FALSE
```

When I click "delete" on the first row, I need all the record about "ken" inside the "UserDetail" table to be removed. Meanwhile, all the record about "ken" in the AspNetDB.mdf will be gone, including UserinRole table.

I am new to asp.net, so I don't know how to pass the commandargument of the "Delete_LinkButton" to the code-behind file LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e), because I need one extra parameter "UserName".

My partial code is listed below:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
                 <ItemTemplate>
                     <asp:LinkButton ID="Delete_LinkButton" runat="server" onclick="LinkButton1_Click1" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("UserName","{0}") %>'>LinkButton</asp:LinkButton>
                 </ItemTemplate>
             </asp:TemplateField>


protected void Delete_LinkButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
      ((LinkButton) GridView1.FindControl("Delete_LinkButton")).Attributes.Add("onclick", "'return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete {0} '" + UserName);
      Membership.DeleteUser(UserName);
      JobPostDataContext db = new JobPostDataContext();
      var query = from u in db.UserDetails
                   where u.UserName == UserName
                   select u;
         for (var Item in query)
         {
              db.UserDetails.DeleteOnSubmit(Item);
         }
      db.SubmitChanges();


     }
```

Please do help!

Comment: Kindly take a look at this one [ASP.NET GridView Button Event][1]. Hope it will help you out.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1508134/asp-net-gridview-button-event

Answer (score 1):

For the confirm, you should add the script to the `OnClientClick` property of the LinkButton:

```
<asp:LinkButton 
    ID="Delete_LinkButton" 
    runat="server" 
    onclick="LinkButton1_Click1" 
    CommandArgument='<%# Eval("UserName","{0}") %>'
    OnClientClick='if (!confirm("Are you sure you want to delete <%# Eval("UserName","{0}") %>?")) return false;'
>
    LinkButton
</asp:LinkButton>
```

And your event handler for that button should be:

```
protected void Delete_LinkButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string userName = ((LinkButton)sender).CommandArgument.ToString();

    Membership.DeleteUser(UserName);
    JobPostDataContext db = new JobPostDataContext();

     foreach (var item in db.UserDetails.Where(u => u.UserName == userName))
          db.UserDetails.DeleteOnSubmit(Item);

    db.SubmitChanges();
}
```

The `OnClientClick` property adds the JavaScript you write to it to the beggining of the onclick property of the rendered `<a/>` tag. So, if the user does not confirm the delete, it will return false and do nothing. Else, it will do the postback to delete.

In the event handler, the `sender` is always the control who originated the event. In this case, the `LinkButton`. So, you can cast it to `LinkButton` and get its `CommandArgument` property, where tye `UserName` is.